# Windows Media Player Burn to ISO

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, windows-media-player

Using Windows Media Player to burn a physical disc is simple. My current workflow is Mp3 files => WMP => physical CD => ISO.

However, I would like to burn to an ISO directly instead, to save the physical media. How can I accomplish this? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: How are you currently creating the ISO images? Do you use WMP to burn actual audio CDs, or rather data CDs containing MP3 files? CDBurnerXP allows directly creating an ISO for a data CD (without burning). But according to its website, it's [not possible to create an ISO for an audio CD](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/createiso).

Comment: @TimDeBaets Audio CD -- I've found solutions that allow me put the MP3's into an ISO but not using WMP to burn an audio CD. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to share those solutions here? I think other users would be interested to read them too.

Comment: @TimDeBaets MP3's into an ISO is with ImgBurn. It's still not making an audio CD that can be mounted and ripped though.

Comment: Indeed, you're probably just creating an ISO for a data CD containing MP3s - not for an audio CD containing actual CD tracks.

Answer (score 0):

#### However, I would like to burn to an ISO instead. How can I accomplish this?

Right-click on the `.iso` file and click "Burn disc image".

Comment: That works if I had an ISO and wanted to create a physical disc. My goal here is to create an audio CD image without doing from Media Player -> Physical CD -> ISO.

Answer (score 0):

PowerISO & MagicDisc are my 2 go-to programs for dealing with .iso files.  You might use PowerISO instead of WMP to make the .iso, and MagicDisc could mount that file as though you have a "virtual" CD-DVD-drive attached to your computer.  I'm not sure, but it might even be possible to make WMP target a MagicDisc virtual drive as though it was a cd-rom ready to "burn" a CD, but it would create an .iso file instead.  Then your workflow from WMP would be pretty much the same, you'd just have to turn on MagicDisc and mount a virtual drive before "saving" your media.

Comment: MagicDisc will not install on Windows 10.